# Mongodb and indexing

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

Two questions:

- If I remove all the data inside a collection (db.mycollection.remove({})) will the indexing information I created previously be lost?
- How often (how many more entries must I have) should I recreate the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Calling `remove()` will remove the indexed data but not the indexes themselves (dropping a collection will do that). So when you insert new documents they will be added to the indexes you created prior to the `remove()` call.
2. You don't need to recreate the index. Once you've created an index it will automatically be updated as documents are inserted / updated / removed.