# How to "defragment" MongoDB index effectively in production?

Tags: indexing, mongodb, admin

I've been looking at MongoDB.  Feels good.

I added some indexes to a collection, uploaded a bunch of data, then removed all the data, and I noticed the indexes did not change size, similar to the behavior reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745812/two-questions-about-mongodb-and-indexing/1746901#1746901).

If I call

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

the indexes are then squashed to near-zero.    Similarly if I don't remove all the data, but call repairDatabase(), the indexes are squashed somewhat (perhaps because unused extends are truncated?).  I am getting index size from "totalIndexSize" of db.collection.stats().

However, that takes a long time (I've read it could be hours on a large database).  It's unclear to me how available the database is for reads or writes while it is running.  I am guessing not so available.

Since I want to run as few instances of mongod as possible, I want to understand more about how indexes are managed after deletes.  Can anyone point me to anything or give any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize David's [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966687/reducing-mongodb-database-file-size):

- No way except db.repairDatabase().
- If you need to minimize downtime, set up a master/slave configuration, and "repairDatabase" the slave, then switch slave and master.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Reducing MongoDB database file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966687/reducing-mongodb-database-file-size) answers your question.