# MongoDB key-value DB alternative with compression

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I am currently using MongoDB to store lots of real-time signals of some sensors. The stored information includes a timestamp, a numeric value and a flag that indicates the quality of the signal.

Queries are very fast but the amount of disk used is exorbitant and would like to try other non-relational database most suitable to my purposes.

I've been looking at http://nosql-database.org/ but I don't know which database is the best for my needs.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Is each set a whole document, or do you group a few of them into one?

Comment: Timestamp, numeric value and flag....Is your data suitable for compression?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB stores field names inside every document, which is great because it allows all documents to have different fields, but creates a storage overhead when fields are always the same.

To reduce the disk consumption, try shortening the field names, so instead of:

```
{
    _id: "47cc67093475061e3d95369d",
    timestamp: "2011-06-09T17:46:21",
    value: 314159,
    quality: 3
}
```

Try this:

```
{
    _id: "47cc67093475061e3d95369d",
    t: "2011-06-09T17:46:21",
    v: 314159,
    q: 3
}
```

Then you can map these field names to something more meaningful inside your application.

Also, if you're storing separate `_id` and `timestamp` fields then you might be doubling up.
The ObjectId type has a [timestamp embedded](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-TimeStamp) in it, so depending on how you query and use your data, it might mean you can do without a separate timestamp field all together.

Answer (score 1):

Disk space is cheap, don't care about this, development with new database will cost much more... If you on windows you can try [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/).

Also mb take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966687/reducing-mongodb-database-file-size/2975296#2975296) answer about reducing mongo database size:

> You can do this "compression" by running mongod --repair or by
>   connecting directly and running db.repairDatabase().