# MongoDB/GridFS out of disk space

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I'm using MongoDB 2.0.6, and I ran out of disk space and can't seem to do anything to clear some up.

I have 3 shards (not replicated, since I can regenerate the photos).

I have one collection called photos, with sharding enabled.  I store everything in gridfs so db.photos.files and db.photos.chunks.

All the files ended up on my primary shard and are not distributed eventhough sharding is enabled on my collection.

When I try:

```
>  db.runCommand({ shardcollection : "photos.fs.chunks", key : { files_id : 1 }})
```

I get an error about needing to create the index.
When I try to create the index I get "Can't take a write lock while out of disk space".

When I try to delete things:

```
>db.fs.files.remove({$and: [{_id: {$gt: "1667"} }, { _id: {$lt: "5000"} }]});
Can't take a write lock while out of disk space
```

Any ideas?

Comment: found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966687/reducing-mongodb-database-file-size