# Free MongoDB disk space

Tags: mongodb, space, repair

I'm having problems with MongoDB excessive use of space. I had a Collection using 8 GB of space. I was trying to compact this space using mongo command "db.repairDatabase()" but it got worst. The Collection now uses 11 GB of space! I found the "compact" command could be useful in that way, but it increased use of space to 17 GB!

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/15801335/604876

Comment: No, I'm a little afraid to drop a database that is used on production.

Comment: I have this same problem. I "compacted" a collection and free space went from 15gb to 6.6gb! Quite the opposite of my intentions.