# Mongo DB Collection Compact

Tags: mongodb, compact-database

I have been looking at a way to reduce the size of a set of mongo databases that keep on growing in size.  I am new to mongodb. I have looked at various methods for doing this and thought the following code might be the simplest way of achieving this without writing code for the specific databases:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin"); 
dbs = db.runCommand({ "listDatabases": 1 }).databases; 

// Iterate through each database and get its collections. 
dbs.forEach(function(database) { 
    db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name); 
    db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (collectionName) { 
        print('Compacting: ' + collectionName); 
        db.runCommand({ compact: collectionName }); 
        db.runCommand({ repairDatabase: 1 } ); 
    }); 
});
```

However, this runs on all databases and so I wasn't sure if this could be potentially dangerous to run?

Comment: this works well from mongo shell / linux command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/#dbcmd.compact) mentions that it's probably a good idea to have a backup when running compact, however outside of [Operation Termination](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/#operation-termination) they do not specifically list a reason why.

It also says that it will block the operations for the database while the command is running so it's probably not a good idea to do this outside of the scheduled maintenance hours.