# mongo collection stats size is larger than exported json

Tags: mongodb

I am surprised because I import json data into mongo. As a result, the json data is noticeably smaller than the collection stats `size`. I did export (with `mongoexport`) the collection into json file again and the collection `size` is 2.4G when an exported json file is 1.8G. Expectation would be that the `size` would be at least the same as json file. Any ideas to explain that? I have not found anything in the documentation.

From docs:

> collStats.size
>
> The total uncompressed size in memory of all records in a collection. The size does not include the size of any indexes associated with the collection, which the totalIndexSize field reports.
>
> The scale argument affects this value. Data compression does not affect this value.

MongoDB version is 4.2. The docs have never been removed or updated. The only operation was `insertMany`.

Comment: Is the difference maybe from removed docs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966687/reducing-mongodb-database-file-size

Comment: No, docs have never been removed.

Comment: Updated? Updates can lead to a disk page splitting into two if it increased in size

Comment: Neah, it is dumb sequencial inserting with batches using pymongo.